# How to Update Multiple Rows in a Android Database?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

First time using an Android database for my application. I've researched update statements and I keep seeing examples using a single row ID to update but what if I use a composite key? The only way to find a unique row is with a season number and team name and my database. So I need to create a statement like..

```
UPDATE table_name
SET wins=5, losses=3
WHERE Team_Name='Something' AND Season='1;
```

Is this possible? There could be multiple rows(around 8), I would need to do this at a time. And would probably use variables for team name and what not. Thanks for any help.

Comment: for your info you can do almost everything in sqlite database as you do in MySQL except some data type restrictions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.  If your season is a string then you would use:

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET wins = 5, losses = 3 
WHERE Team_Name = 'Something' 
AND Season = '1'
```

However, if your season is a number then you would use:

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET wins = 5, losses = 3 
WHERE Team_Name = 'Something' 
AND Season = 1
```

Comment: So could I just create a String with the update query within a method and at the end db.execSQL(QueryString)

Comment: Yes, `execSQL(String sql)`is for executing a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL statement that returns data.

Comment: You have SQL Server running on an Android device? What is it with all those tag updates?